# PostgreSQL Upsert (On Conflict) with same values in Insert and Update

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Can I simplify the syntax when I use the same values in an Insert... On Conflict statment?

```
INSERT INTO cars 
  (car_id, car_type, car_model) 
values
  (1, 'tesla', 'model s')
ON CONFLICT (car_id) DO UPDATE SET 
  car_type = 'tesla',
  car_model = 'model s';
```

There are many more statements of this kind because they are part of a script that gets run on every application update.

Bascially I am looking for a way to not specify the same value twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`excluded`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) keyword:

```
INSERT INTO cars 
  (car_id, car_type, car_model) 
values
  (1, 'tesla', 'model s')
ON CONFLICT (car_id) DO UPDATE SET 
  car_type = excluded.car_type,
  car_model = excluded.car_model;
```

This also works correctly with multiple rows, e.g:

```
INSERT INTO cars 
  (car_id, car_type, car_model) 
values
  (1, 'tesla', 'model s'), 
  (2, 'toyota', 'prius')
ON CONFLICT (car_id) DO UPDATE SET 
  car_type = excluded.car_type,
  car_model = excluded.car_model;
```

Comment: This looks great. Do you have to specify the excluded columns, even if all values should be updated?

Comment: @tommy: yes, unfortunately.